# Sometimes App is not giving notification of iBeacon when app is kill by user in ios

Tags: ios, geolocation, ibeacon

I am using iBeacon Technology in my application.When I open the app,beacon monitoring gets started and after that I kill the application and put the phone in sleep mode or lock the screen. If I go near to the beacon then sometimes app starts monitoring and sometimes not. Don't know what's the issue? I have set three flag for monitoring beacon region as below.

```
beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true;  
beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = true;
beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay= true;
```

And When I press the lock button of the iphone. It starts monitoring for beacons and if I am in beacon region then it works perfectly..

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Did you followed AirLocation demo code base from apple it's very good to start from there. Also share your background notification code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with iBeacon for around a year now, i have had the same scenarios encountered.
As per my experience with this if you are already inside a region, it takes some time to notify the 'didEnterRegion' delegate method. But if you are outside region a then entering the same you are likely to get the delegate called instantly and this depends on the Beacon Manufacture you are testing with. [More accuracy were found with RadBeacon, Estimote and Kontakt ]

Normally the TxPower configured to the beacons will be +4 dBm thats a Beacon can transmit till 70m/230". Try with going out of the region with the App in killed state and then enter the region.

When we set notifyOnEntry, notifyOnExit to YES/true, the control is with the OS LocationManager wether to notify the App about the region entry state, and you can handle it with a Notification thrown to the User and start Monitoring and then Ranging for the encountered region.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. So you mean to say that it depends upon the beacon also? correct?

Comment: But I am not able to receive the notification when I have kill the app and I have not lock the phone in iOS 7.1.. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Arpit I have the same problem after killing the app. Is there way to receive notification about my state at this position right after app is killed? Now I got notifications only after state changes.